# UIViewcontroller's view frame starting at unexpected location

Tags: ios7

We are started to convert our iOS 6 application into iOS 7. I tried to create one screen for my application. I used Xib file for design, I designed the screen from top to bottom with UILabel and UIButtons. When I tried to run the app in Simulator it showing differently from **xib** design. In simulator the designs are came down and bottom UILabel has hide.

I got the self.view.frame from **viewDidLoad()** was **(0,64,32,504)**. But, it is showing correctly in viewDidAppear **(0,0,320,568)**.

How can I resolve this issue in Xcode 5? Could you please help me to solve this.Looking forward your reply. Thanks.

Comment: are you putting the necessary constraints in your xib?

Comment: Yes i tried self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO and self.edgesforextendedlayout = uirectedgenone. But, no response. I don't know whether I tried in right way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot depend on the frame in -viewDidLoad, because it hasn't been resized for the device at that point. You need to wait for -viewDidAppear.

Comment: Actually this screen was designed in Xib file. This is first time am facing this problem. Could you pls guide me to resolve this prob?

Comment: You need to elaborate what the problem is. In the first paragraph you seem to say the problem is in the simulator, but then you say it shows correct in -viewDidAppear. Post code and/or screenshots.

Comment: Yes I designed the screen in Xib and launched in Simulator the bottom controls are hide so, I just checked the frame size by code in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear delegates. I am not able to post screen shot becoz SOF blocked in office :(.